# animation character not working

Tags: animation, rigging

I made a character in makehuman and imported it in blender and then I downloaded the animation of dancing from cmuconvert and loaded it and played the animation and it shows like this [image: tion]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know cmuconvert, but I know for sure that animations are not compatible with any rig. Basically, an animation can be used on your rig only if your rig is quite close to the rig used for creating the animation. Including bone names.

That being said, I did some research and found [this thread](https://www.makehumancommunity.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=44660&sid=f877514a1a0adda89af37f5f6f5c3dde#p44660) about importing animations from cmu.
You might find the needed plugins [here](https://www.makehumancommunity.org/content/plugins.html).